# The space of alternating multilinear forms

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, terminology

I was just wondering if there is a standard (or even just usual) notation for the space of alternating $k$-linear forms on an $F$-vector space. I know that this space is naturally isomorphic to the dual of the $k$th exterior power of $V$, namely $(\Lambda^{\!k}\,V)^*$, but is it usual to denote this space in this way?

Many thanks!

Comment: More commonly one sees $\Lambda^k V^*$, to which both of the spaces you mentioned are again canonically isomorphic.

Comment: But that's only true if $V$ is finite-dimensional, right?